# Eliminating the Storyboard Completed handler in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

A little background:

I'm building a window and I've got a Storyboard that I use to show briefly a popup upon completion of a user-initiated task without need for user confirmation. It looks something like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadingFeedback" x:Key="FadingFeedback" Completed="FadingFeedback_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation  
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                         From="0.5" 
                         To="0" 
                         BeginTime="0:0:0" 
                         Duration="0:0:2.0">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ExponentialEase Exponent="10" EasingMode="EaseIn" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The popup I'm using is defined like so:

```
<Popup Name="popup" Placement="Center" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True"
       IsOpen="{Binding DoShowMessage}">
    <Popup.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DoShowMessage}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Popup.IsOpen" Value="true" />
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadingFeedback}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Popup.Style>
    <Border Background="Black" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid Name="popupGrid" Background="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
            <Label Name="popupLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
               FontSize="16"
               Content="{Binding TextMessage}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

There's a ViewModel that is the datacontext for this and it's got a couple of properties (referenced there in the Bindings) to provide the TextMessage string and the DoShowMessage bool.  They are defined something like this:

```
    private string _textMessage;
    public string TextMessage
    {
        get { return _textMessage; }
        set
        {
            _textMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextMessage");
        }
    }

    private bool _doShowMessage;
    public bool DoShowMessage
    {
        get { return _doShowMessage; }
        set
        {
            _doShowMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DoShowMessage");
        }
    }
```

And when appropriate the ViewModel will set the `DoShowMessage` property and the binding in the XAML will show the popup and begin the storyboard.

Right now, I've got `Completed` handler in the code behind for the popup that just does this:

```
    void StatusFader_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

and that works well enough, and since `popup.IsOpen` is bound to the underlying property on the ViewModel `DoShowMessage`, it will reset that boolean.

The question I have:

Is there a "better" way to handle the reset of that DoShowMessage property when the storyboard is done?  Or perhaps differently put, is there a way to do that in the XAML itself?  I've read the opinion/convention that the code behind should be (mostly) devoid of code for the views but it seems (at least to me) that this (the event handler) is a reasonable way to do it.  Wondering if there's a way to do that in the XAML though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you can do it in another way. Setting `popup.IsOpen="False"` via `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.

For example:

`Storyboard`

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FadingFeedback" x:Key="FadingFeedback"> 
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.5" 
                             To="0" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2.0">

        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <ExponentialEase Exponent="10" EasingMode="EaseIn" />
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Popup Name="popup" Placement="Center" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding DoShowMessage}">
    <Popup.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DoShowMessage}" Value="True">
                <!--<Setter Property="Popup.IsOpen" Value="True" />--> <!-- not necessarily, because we have Popup.IsOpen = True -->

                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadingFeedback}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </Popup.Style>  
    ...
</Popup>
```

But in this case, the opening `Popup` outside animation is problematic, because of this the properties of animation is a first priority, however other sources, such as a code, designate will not. Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx):

> In order to have any practical effect, an animation of a property must be able to have precedence over the base (unanimated) value, even if that value was set locally.

So that would be accessed through the code, remove the animation from the property, therefore allowing access to the property, like so:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="CloseButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)" 
                                                    Duration="0:0:0">

                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" Width="200" Height="200" IsOpen="True">
        <Grid Background="Azure">
            <Label Content="Test label" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>

    <Button Name="OpenButton" Content="OpenButtonFromCode" Width="140" Height="30" Click="OpenButton_Click" />
    <Button Name="CloseButton" Content="CloseButtonfromEventTrigger" Width="180" Height="30" Margin="0,80,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.BeginAnimation(Popup.IsOpenProperty, null);
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

There is a choice, or simply drop in the `popup.IsOpen` of *False* in the event `Storyboard_Completed`, or do it in animation, but to access a code, it must be removed.

For myself, I usually do so, create a attached dependency property (boolean), that bound trigger animation to this property. If the value of it true, starts the animation, but it is to be re-run, in the event `Storyboard_Completed` I had to fold property to false. Personally for me, it's an easier way.

Comment: Thanks Anatoliy - I'm reading over what you wrote and trying to decide what makes sense for me here.